# Error while launching URDF in RVIZ: "junk after document element"

Tags: gazebo, ros2, rviz, urdf, ros2-launch

I have followed the Nav2 tutorial for setting up my URDF, but this error had me stuck on section1  for days. Knowingly, I'm using the URDF and mesh files from an open repository https://github.com/freefloating-gazebo/bluerov_ffg/tree/master/urdf and the rest of files from the Nav2 tut https://navigation.ros.org/setup_guides/urdf/setup_urdf.html.
Everytime I launch, this error occurs:

````
 [ERROR] [launch]: Caught exception in launch (see debug for traceback): executed command failed. Command: xacro /home/salma/bluerov/install/bluerov/share/bluerov/src/urdf/brov2_uwsim.urdf
Captured stderr output: XML parsing error: junk after document element: line 137, column 0
when processing file: /home/salma/bluerov/install/bluerov/share/bluerov/src/urdf/brov2_uwsim.urdf

Check that:
 - Your XML is well-formed
 - You have the xacro xmlns declaration: xmlns:xacro="http://www.ros.org/wiki/xacro"
```
````